# Evaluation Time while modifying curve

Tags: animation, bezier-curves

I have a curve used to control the camera path with the Evaluation Time. If now I want to make small changes to the curve (even adjusting a single vertex) the whole Evaluation goes Off, forcing to readjusting the whole Evaluation keyframing.
Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this trick: Create aplane, parent the camera to 3 vertices of this plane (select the camera, shift select the plane, select 3 of its vertices, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> to parent), give a *Curve* modifier to the plane, move the plane along the correct axis, with this method you can extrude the curve and the camera won't move:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I give it a try!